# Cannot load project using .NET Core after installing Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have installed the community Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4.
and clone the solution of .NET Core 3.0 but no project loaded something wrong in the SDK.
I have installed the SDK and runtime for 3.0 and 3.1, but still can not load any project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix the VS 2019 issue with the below steps

- Run `dotnet --list-sdks` to know the exact version of the SDK installed
- Modify the global.json file in the root folder of the project (For example,the project was showing 3.0.100 but you had 3.0.101 installed, you need to edit the same to point to that version and you could be able to reload the projects.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json#globaljson-and-the-net-core-cli

Comment: I have tried this solution but it does not work, but when i took a copy of project from another device it works fine the problem when i try to clone project for first time

Comment: In my case `dotnet --list-sdks` is empty and `dotnet --info` says ".NET SDKs installed: No SDKs were found." while Apps and Features shows 6 different .NET SDKs installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I uninstalled Visual Studio 2022 Preview. Removing the C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\ directory from my PATH variable solved it.